# Google Maps API (v3) adding/updating markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**EDIT: It now works, but does not load if the user does not allow or have location-based services. See accepted answer comment for jsfiddle example.**

I've looked through a few tutorials and questions but I can't quiet understand what's happening (or in this case, not happening). I'm loading my map when the user clicks a link. This loads the map with the users current location in the center, and a marker at the users location. However, any markers outside of the `if (navigation.location)` don't seem to load. Below is my current code:

```
function initialize() {
        // Check if user support geo-location
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                var userLat = position.coords.latitude;
                var userLong = position.coords.longitude;
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: 8,
                    center: point,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                }

            // Initialize the Google Maps API v3
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

            // Place a marker
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: map,
                title: 'Your GPS Location'
            });
        });
    } else {
        var userLat = 53;
        var userLong = 0;
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(userLat, userLong),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        }
        // Place a marker
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: point,
            map: map,
            title: 'Default Location'
        });
        // Initialize the Google Maps API v3
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    }
    <?
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($userLocations); $i++) {
        ?>
        var userLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $userLocations[$i]['lat']; ?>, <? echo $userLocations[$i]['long']; ?>);
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: userLatLong,
            map: map,
            title:"<? echo $userLocations[$i]['displayName'] . ', ' . $userLocations[$i]['usertype']; ?>"
        });
        <?
    }
    ?>
}

function loadMapScript() {
    if (typeof(loaded) == "undefined") {
        $("#showMap").css("display", "none");
        $("#showMapLink").removeAttr("href");
        $("#map").css("height", "600px");
        $("#map").css("width", "600px");
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        loaded = true;
    } else {
        alert("Map already loaded!");
    }
}
```

loadMapScript() is called when the user clicks a link. The php for loop loops through a pre-created array with all the information.
I'm guessing I don't fully understand it, as when if I put:

```
var userLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(53, 0);
            new google.maps.Marker({
                position: userLatLong,
                map: map,
                title:"Title"
            });
```

into the console (Google Chrome), I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid value for property <map>: [object HTMLDivElement]
```

I don't, however, get any errors otherwise. Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: How does `loadMapScript()` get called?

Comment: When the user clicks a link to `loadMapScript()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous.

Reorganize your code like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
}

function initialize() {
    // Check if user support geo-location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            makeMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, 'Your GPS Location');
        });
    } else {
        makeMap(53, 0, 'DefaultLocation');
    }
}

function makeMap(lat, lng, text) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    mapOptions.center = point;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        map: map,
        title: text
    });
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($userLocations); $i++): ?>
    var userLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $userLocations[$i]['lat']; ?>, <? echo $userLocations[$i]['long']; ?>);
    new google.maps.Marker({
        position: userLatLong,
        map: map,
        title:"<? echo $userLocations[$i]['displayName'] . ', ' . $userLocations[$i]['usertype']; ?>"
    });
    <?php endforeach ?>
}
```

Also, consider bootstraping the $userLocations into a JavaScript variable like this:

```
var userLocations = <?php print json_encode($userLocations) ?>;
```

Then execute your for loop in JavaScript, instead of mixing languages.

Comment: Moved the `var mapOptions` to inside `makeMap` so that I can load the map after page load. It now (seems) to work. Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, I tell a lie. It still doesn't load if the user doesn't allow location (of doesn't have a location-enabled browser). Repeatable on your jsfiddle example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/eSnhg/2/ - fixed. Add a function to handle denial as the second parameter to getCurrentPosition().

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
var map = null;
function initialize() { ... }
```

and then changing the code inside:

```
map = new google.maps.Map( ... ); //make this the first line
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    // Change the code from:
    var map ...
    // to:
    map ...
```

You just reference the map directly (without the `var`) everywhere else, so that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

To:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
```

Because of `var`, your map variable is tied the the scope of `initialize()`. Removing it will set it as the global map variable (or `window.map`), making it available outside of the `initialize()` function.

What's happening is you have an HTML element `<div id="map">`. In many browsers, global variables are created from html element ids, so `map` equals `document.getElementById('map')`.

---

**Edit:** Actually, this only explains your problem in the Chrome console. You need to set `map` before trying to attach markers to it, as you do within `if (navigator.geolocation) {}`. This also explains why none of the user location markers are being placed. The code to place them runs **before** `initialize()`. Put this code either within `initialize` or within its own function, and call that function from `initialize`.

Comment: The code that adds the markers is within the `initialize()` function, and comes after the declaration of `map`. I did actually spot your first change, but as you say, it wasn't the problem.

Comment: Sorry for double post. I have also re-tried the initial change, and also declare `var map;` at the top of the `initialize()` function, but no joy.

Comment: Have you tested on a browser without geolocation detection? `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` is asynchronous, whereas the code that plots the points is synchronous. It runs before the callback, in which you initialize your google map.

Comment: I was going to test that after, but I tried it just now, and the map won't even appear. No errors, just doesn't show and my div is empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're creating the marker, but not doing anything with it. Try changing your new Marker to look like this:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: point,  // this won't actually work - point is out of scope
               title: 'Your GPS Location'
           });

marker.setMap(map);
```

Edit: Make sure the point is inside the map!

```
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(point);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: This isn't necessary; including a `map` property as part of the `MapOptions` object that is passed to the `google.maps.Marker` constructor takes care of it. It looks like a scope issue.

Comment: Tried  `var userLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $userLocations[$i]['lat']; ?>, <? echo $userLocations[$i]['long']; ?>);
   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: userLatLong,
    map: map,
    title:"<? echo $userLocations[$i]['displayName'] . ', ' . $userLocations[$i]['usertype']; ?>"
   });
   marker.setMap(map);
   console.log('Adding marker at userLatLong = ' + userLatLong);`  This puts a log in the console, but no marker. EDIT: Whoops, that's not very well formatted :(

Comment: Well, I don't remember why, but I did it in my code above, and it works :)  But the problem could be that the point var is not in scope.

Comment: @JosephDuffy: are you sure the marker is inside the bounds of that maps as displayed?  Try resetting the bounds as per my edit.

Comment: @chris I have been outputting the marker position in the console, and I'm getting (53, 0), which is well within the limits. I have tried other values, too. I'll add your try your edit after some food!