# Add customize place by marking it on google map api

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

i'm working at security company and it provide dvr home camera security service. i want to display my technical group to  where the places we supply the service and where the break down places,while break down place indicate in red and others in green.  i need to add new place by marking it on the map and change the status of the place whether break down or not? how can i do it with google map jquery plugin,ajax and php.if there is appropriate jquery plugin pls tel me. here is a picture for further idea[image]

Comment: try updating that particular place with red color marker,while showing markers with latlang.

Comment: pls i hope sample code if you can,i'm new to google map api

Comment: try this may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487003/google-maps-api-v3-adding-updating-markers

Comment: sorry! i can't get that.is there any plugin to set location and remeber it in table.